# ui:list Failed to save

Tags: lightning-aura-components, list, aura

I'm looking to build a list component using ui:list or ui:infiniteList

Somthing like:

```
<aura:component controller="FeedItemController" >
   <aura:attribute name="FeedItems" type="List" />
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

   <ui:list itemVar="{!v.FeedItems}" var="FeedItem">
      {!FeedItem.Body}"
   </ui:list>
</aura:component>
```

However, I'm getting a "Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named list found: Source" error. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your `ui:list` and `ui:infiniteList` in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ui_lists.htm), but they're not actually in the Spring 17 release (e.g. they are not listed in the [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm)). My guess is that someone accidentally posted some Summer 17 content early, and that these features will be available around June 2017.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, as it is part of the aura framework. But I know it's not been fully implemented.